# Get the Sum of given number in scheme

Tags: scheme

Hi i want my function to sum digits such that the result is less than 10 (77 = 14=5). dont know why it's passing the base case

```
(define (reduct n)
  (if(< n 10) n
     (+(modulo n 10)(reduct (truncate(/ n 10))))))
```

Comment: Hint: `(define (reduct n) (modulo n 9))`. Study any numerology site to learn why.

Comment: is that actually a hint? o_O sorry

Comment: I've elaborated on it some in the last paragraph of my answer. Basically, unless this is for homework and you're required to do it recursively for some reason, my one-liner is a much faster solution.

Comment: thanks for elaborating, very well explained for a "non-logic thinker" like me lol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `reduct` again after adding. Here's the fixed version:

```lisp
(define (reduct n)
  (if (< n 10)
      n
      (reduct (+ (modulo n 10) (reduct (quotient n 10))))))
```

Note that the inner `reduct` recursion is actually redundant and can be removed, leaving:

```lisp
(define (reduct n)
  (if (< n 10)
      n
      (reduct (+ (modulo n 10) (quotient n 10)))))
```

or, if you want to only divide once (and get the modulo too), you can use the R7RS `floor/` procedure:

```lisp
(define (reduct n)
  (if (< n 10)
      n
      (reduct (call-with-values (lambda () (floor/ n 10)) +))))
```

(This is, by the way, a pure loop. A Ruby version could look like:

```rb
def reduct(n)
  n = n % 10 + n / 10 while n >= 10
  n
end
```

or (for the one-division-only approach)

```rb
def reduct(n)
  n = n.divmod(10).reduce(:+) while n >= 10
  n
end
```

except that it uses mutation unlike the Scheme version.)

However, as my comment already says, the result will always be the same as doing `(modulo n 9)` (except that 0 should become 9, so `(+ (modulo (- n 1) 9) 1)` is probably more correct), so if you're doing this for numerological purposes or otherwise not a homework which requires you to do it the "hard way", just use that.